# Django - how to get inputs from the user and return queryset based by

Tags: python, django, post, django-queryset, reporting

I want to make kind of a reporting tool for end users, Like if we have a book model in the database, the user will select the author to filter by and will receive a filtered queryset

what is the proper way to do this?
Is this a proper one?: 1- a form+template | 2- filter the queryset by the inputs | 3- return the queryset

if this a right approach how should I get the inputs in the code for filtering? should I use get and post?

Comment: 1.make model
2.make view set with query (use class view set)
3.make URLs for that
* register model in admin file (optional if wants to see the database in Django admin)
5.make a template that accepts input

done

Comment: @ShahVipul how do I get those inputs in my code to filter the queryset?

Comment: use Django form that will with 
make a form file
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/
check this here